# Missing FragmentFactory class and getFragmentFactory() method in FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I'm trying to implement a hierarchical multi-screen settings for my app. I'm following the ["Organize your settings" guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#kotlin), which contains an example implementation of a function that should construct a new Fragment instance using the [FragmentFactory class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentFactory):

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
        classLoader,
        pref.fragment,
        args)
```

However, the IDE cannot resolve neither this class or the `fragmentFactory` property of `FragmentManager`.

I'm using the following support libraries:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.0.0'
```

Is it possible that the guide refers to not-yet-stable features?

Comment: by the way, the instantiate method takes no args anymore - so remove the args parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this class is available in [`androidx.fragment` since version 1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#2018-nov). Currently it's still in alpha and I'm only using stable lib versions for production.

Comment: So how do you instantiate a new Fragment?